# Angular: How can I use a directive to format an input value?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I tried to create a custom directive to allow users to type only numbers in a text field and those numbers will be formatted using the locale format (thousands separators, decimal separator)

I have been able to create a directive that use a custom pipe to do so, however, I can't set the default value using the correct format.

I've made a Plunker so that you know exactly what I'm talking about :

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/ToxPEEooR5lvCJOm?preview

I don't know why but I can't make the demo app on Plunker work. Probably a small issue.

Here is my directive

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NumberMaskPipe } from './number-mask.pipe';

@Directive({
  selector: 'input[type=text][numberMask]'
})
export class NumberMaskDirective implements OnInit {

  private el: HTMLInputElement;
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-input-rename
  @Input('ngModel') private initialValue: any;

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private numberMaskPipe: NumberMaskPipe
  ) {
    this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit', this.initialValue); // LOG ngOnInit 1005698
    console.log(this.numberMaskPipe.transform(this.initialValue)); // LOG 1,005,698.00
    console.log('this.el', this.el); // LOG this.el <input _ng2content-c2 class="form-control...
    console.log('this.el.value', this.el.value); // this.el.value is empty on init. Why ??
    this.el.value = this.numberMaskPipe.transform(this.initialValue); // Does not change the input value. Why ??
  }

  @HostListener('focus', ['$event.target.value'])
  onFocus(value) {
    this.el.value = this.numberMaskPipe.parse(value); // opposite of transform
  }

  @HostListener('blur', ['$event.target.value'])
  onBlur(value) {
    this.el.value = this.numberMaskPipe.transform(value);
  }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) {
    const e = < KeyboardEvent > event;
    if ([46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
      // Allow: Ctrl+A
      (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
      // Allow: Ctrl+C
      (e.keyCode === 67 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
      // Allow: Ctrl+V
      (e.keyCode === 86 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
      // Allow: Ctrl+X
      (e.keyCode === 88 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
      // Allow: home, end, left, right
      (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
      // let it happen, don't do anything
      return;
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

Could you please tell me how to initialize the input field with its value formatted using my directive ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The data for the DOM element is not yet bound when `ngOnInit()` fires for any attached directives so the value is bound afterwards and any changes made in the directives' `ngOnInit()` are lost. The only way I have found you can fire a function after the data has been bound in a directive is to implement `DoCheck`.

So you would want to do something like this:

```js
export class NumberMaskDirective implements DoCheck {
private firstRun = true;

public ngDoCheck() {
    if (firstRun) {
        this.el.value = this.numberMaskPipe.transform(this.initialValue);
        firstRun = false;
    }
}
```

The reason for the flag is that `ngDoCheck` is called every time the data model is updated. You could also use `ngAfterContentChecked` or `ngAfterViewChecked` but they have the same problem as `ngDoCheck` of firing on every update so I'm just going with `ngDoCheck` because it fires first of all three of these hooks. I am not sure if there is a better lifecycle hook to use that does not require a flag to ensure it only runs once, but I have not been able to find one.